# Python pandas read_sql converting string to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read data into pandas from an sql database using pandas read_sql. But getting an error which seems to be pandas trying to convert string data to integer, which I don't want it to do.

I am getting the following error message

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ....: ('22018', "[22018] 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when 
converting the nvarchar value 'P62' to data type int. (245) 
(SQLExecDirectW)")
```

P62 is in my databse which for this column is mostly integer values but includes a few string values such as P62. So I want pandas to read it in as string. In SQL the object for the column is nvarchar.

This is my code

```
query = """SELECT [Jaar], [Periode],[Status], [Goederengroep], [GGOmschrijving], [Regkol], [RKOmschrijving], [IOVM], [Lp] FROM [WERK].[vw_WERK_AGTData_Totalen] 
WHERE Jaar=2017 AND Regkol=64200"""

df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_con)
```

Greatful for any help or words of wisdom. It is Friday afternoon so could be my own stupidity.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you able to run the same query directly in the database without error?

Comment: Yes, and also via access.

Comment: Could you try to read it using the parameter coerce_float = False inside pd.read_sql

Comment: @Ivan, tried that same error message.

Comment: do you know the column ? you can declare the dtype in pd.read_sql to avoid the error.

Comment: Yes I know the column. How do I specify the data type. Can't see that option in the readsql docs.